# sql server round function not working well

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am using sql server 2000 and facing round function issue like the following statement working fine.

```
SELECT ROUND(5 * 7.83, 1)
```

The result will be 39.2

But when I get these values from the table, it gives 39.1, meaning it truncates and does not round up.

```
SELECT ROUND(rate * qty, 1) 
  FROM tbl
```

The result will be 39.1

`rate` and `qty` columns data types are float.  Insert 5 in `qty` and 7.83 in `rate`, then check it.  How I can fix it?

Comment: what is the output of select rate,qty from tb1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the table values to real,

```
SELECT ROUND(convert(real,rate)*convert(real,qty),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample simply query is not reflective of the data types involved.

Try these two instead:

```
SELECT ROUND(5 * 7.83, 1)
SELECT ROUND(cast(5 as float) * cast(7.83 as float), 1)
```

The 2nd one matches your table data types.  Float datatypes are not meant for precise decimal calculations, use a decimal type for those instead.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Without losing too much precision for normal numbers, you can just cast to decimal on the fly to force human-comprehensible decimal arithmetics, e.g.

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(rate as decimal(10,5)) * cast(qty as decimal(10,5), 1) 
  FROM tbl
```