# ROUND function versus data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My question is conceptual.

In the code snippet below my expectation is to get exactly the same result for all "round" activations.

However, when using a constant as an argument, the result is different than when using a calculated or stored value.

In the documentation I did not find any comment to help me understand the reason for the difference.

In response to the similar question ([sql server round function not working well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460089/sql-server-round-function-not-working-well)), I was referred to the excellent article https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, but in the following example, all cases are "float", so I don't think there are reasons for different results.

--

```
DECLARE @value FLOAT;
SET @value = 4255.0;
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (
  FLOAT_VALUE FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE(FLOAT_VALUE) VALUES (@value);
SELECT 0.015 * 4255.0 AS ORIGINAL_VALUE,
   ROUND(0.015 * 4255.0, 2) AS ROUND_FROM_CONSTANT, 
   ROUND(0.015 * CONVERT(FLOAT, 4255.0), 2) AS ROUND_FROM_CAST, 
   ROUND(0.015 * @value, 2) AS ROUND_FROM_VARIABLE,
   ROUND(0.015 * FLOAT_VALUE, 2) AS ROUND_FROM_FIELD
FROM TESTTABLE
```

Comment: `4255.0` as a literal is a `decimal(5,1)` not a `float`. Decimals and floats act *very* differently; you shouldn't expect the same behaviour.

Comment: Thank you.
Before its clarification, a complete mystery.
Now, it seemed like a very dummy question

Comment: Just hadn't had a chance yet @ZoharPeled ; busy afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting different results is because you have different data types throughout the expressions.

As a literal, `4225.0` is a `decimal(5,1)` *not* a `float`, so only when you explicitly cast the value to a float will it be treated as one. As a `float` and `decimal` don't operate the same as well, you get different results.

We'll go through each expression:

1. `0.015 * 4255.0`

   These are both `decimal` values, a `decimal(3,3)` and a `decimal(5,1)`. When dealing with different scales and precisions and multiplication, the following is used to calculate them:

   `Precision = p1 + p2 + 1`
   `Scale = s1 + s2`

   Therefore the resulting precision and scale are `3+5+1` and `1+3` = `decimal(9,4)` This is why you get the result `63.8250`.
2. `ROUND(0.015 * 4255.0, 2)`

   Same as above, but then you round to 2 decimal places; little explanation needed here.
3. `ROUND(0.015 * CONVERT(float, 4255.0), 2)`

   There are 2 data types here, the `decimal(3,3)` and the `float`. Use we have 2 different data types, data type precedence comes into play. As a `0.015` is implicitly cast to a `float`.

   `CONVERT(float,0.015) *  CONVERT(float, 4255.0)` returns `63.825`, however, as `float` is an imprecision value, using `ROUND` on that ends up returning `63.82`; because because the number is actually < `63.825` in the imprecise stored value (perhaps `63824999999999~`).
4. `ROUND(0.015 * @value, 2)`

   Same as 3.
5. `ROUND(0.015 * FLOAT_VALUE, 2)`

   Same as 3.

References:

- [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)